# How are "key" functions more efficient than comparison functions in python's sorted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, sorting

In the [Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python](https://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go?t=607) video (link starts at 10:07), the speaker says that using `key` instead of the `cmp` comparison function for sorting is more efficient. To paraphrase: he states that because there are O(nlog(n)) comparisons, a comparison function would be called 20m times for a 1m element list (log2(1m) ~ 20) while using `key` is better because it is called exactly once per key.

I understand his point about how using `key` is more readable, but I don't get how he determined that it's called once per key. I would have thought that under the hood, a sorting function that has a `key` parameter would look something like this:

```
def sort(sequence, key=None):
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x
    def compare(first, second):
        if key(first) < key(second): return -1
        if key(second) < key(first): return 1
        return 0
    # ... implement sorting algorithm
```

And so it would amount to the same time complexity whether we use a key function or a comparison function.

How is the key function only called once per element, if there are O(nlog(n)) comparisons? Is this a [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) implementation detail?

**Edit:**

To address the comment asking for an example:

In python2, the `sorted` function accepted a `cmp` argument, something like this:

```
def compare(first, second):
    if len(first) < len(second): return -1
    if len(second) < len(first): return 1
    return 0

sorted(my_list, cmp=compare)
```

However, you could also pass a key function if you wanted. So, to achieve the same effect as above, you would do this:

```
sorted(my_list, key=len)
```

In the video, the author claims that the second option is more efficient than the first.

Comment: "_using `key` instead of the `cmp`_" makes no sense unless you tell us _where_ any of them is used and provide an example.

Comment: @DYZ I've added the example

Comment: The simplest explanation is you misunderstood the video. Can you cite a time and duration to look at? I'm not watching a 50 minute video.

Comment: The link starts at the point he explains the sorting bit. I'll edit the text around the link to clarify! @KennyOstrom

Comment: You should read about the Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom (also known as a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)). Doing that explicitly was one way to avoid performance problems sorting slow-to-compare items in Python. Using a `key` method lets the sorting code do it all for you.

Comment: @Blckknght Ah! I didn't know about this, if you could elaborate about this in an answer, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before `key` was supported directly by `sorted` and `list.sort`, there was an idiom that allowed you to get its benefits anyway. The idiom was called Decorate-Sort-Undecorate (and it is apparently also known as a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)).

Here's how it works:

```
def sort_with_key(data, keyfunc):
    decorated_data = [(keyfunc(x), i, x) for i, x in enumerate(data)]
    decorated_data.sort()
    return [x for key, i, x in decorated_data]
```

The three lines of the function correspond to the three parts of the idiom's name.

1. The first line "decorates" the data by making a tuple combining a key value and an tiebreaker index with each item from the input. This is the only place the key function gets called, so there are only `O(len(data))` calls.
2. The second step is easy. We sort the decorated list of tuples using the default comparison method. Since tuples are compared lexicographically, for most pairs of items only the key values need to be compared to each other. If there are any ties between key values, the index value in the middle of the tuple will break it (always in such a way that the items remain in the same relative order that they were in in the input list, making it a stable sort). The items from `data` are never compared, since the tiebreaker values will always differ (since they're the indexes of the original list).
3. The last steps is simple to understand as well. We just discard the key and tiebreaker values, producing a list that contains only the original items, in the newly sorted order.

When a `key` parameter was added to `list.sort` and `sorted`, it made the sort functions able to do the whole thing for you automatically. I'm not aware of the exact details of how the key value is stored (you can [read the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/94451182ccd6729c11338926d8a3d11645e86626/Objects/listobject.c) if you really must know), but its effects are the same as the DSU idiom. The key function is called once on each value in the input list, and its results are saved to be compared multiple times later on, when the actual sorting is happening.

Comment: minor typo in decorated_data's initializer, "for i, x"

Answer (score 5):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html):

> Starting with Python 2.4, both list.sort() and sorted() added a key parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element **prior to** making comparisons.

Note the word **prior to**: The keys are calculated not *instead* of calling `cmp`, but *before* it. Calculating the keys takes O(n), but the sorting takes O(n log(n)), so the overall complexity of sorting is still O(n log(n)).

**Edited**

The presenter suggests calculating the string lengths before sorting (via `keys`), which indeed requires n calls to `len`. If the same function is called during sorting (via `cmp`), the number of calls will be at least 2 n log(n).

In short, the number of comparisons is the same in both cases, but the number of calls to `len` differs.

Comment: I watched the clip. The presenter was wrong. However I agree that key functions are better because they are clearer and less error prone. It's just the efficiency statement by the presenter that was plain wrong (as you say).

Comment: @KennyOstrom The presenter was not entirely wrong (see my edit). But he perhaps confused the number of comparisons and the number of calls to `len`.

Comment: The speaker says "The key function is called **exactly once per key**", that's what I don't understand

Comment: What's not to understand? The keys (string lengths) are calculated before sorting, once for each string. The strings are later sorted according to their precomputed lengths.

Comment: ah, IF the comparison function does extra work, that extra work is a constant multiplier, instead of being a simple constant added term for key functions. Good clarification. (Neither is relevant to a computer scientist ... double? irrelevant!)

Comment: @DYZ What I don't understand is this: how would this be implemented? For example, would there be two lists: the original lists and a keys lists, and you sort both lists in parallel and return the original list but sorted?

Comment: It would have to be implemented with extra storage space, yes. And that extra space does have a cost, but don't worry about that! (and to be fair to the presenter, it's python -- calling functions is relatively expensive in python, I think)

Comment: Actually watching it, good presentation. The presenter's point on that particular topic doesn't line up with big-O notation, so we just need a clarification that's not what he's talking about (on that one point). Which DYZ has clarified, so good answer.